# SqlCacheDependency remove callback fires directly after Cache.Add

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldependency, query-notifications

I have a problem with SqlCacheDependency that I cannot wrap my head around.
The CacheItemRemovedCallback will fire as soon as I add something to the cache when using a query for notification (it works when I am using databaseEntryName and tableName but that is to blunt for me). I have checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx about 20 times but I still cannot find what I am doing wrong.

The code I am using:

```
string connString = MsSqlUtil.GetConnectionString();
System.Web.Caching.SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableNotifications(connString);
System.Web.Caching.SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableTableForNotifications(connString, "Product");
SqlDependency.Start(connString);

Product product = ProductProvider.Get(10);

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{

  SqlCommand cmdProduct = new SqlCommand(@"
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  SET ANSI_PADDING ON
  SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
  SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
  SET ARITHABORT ON
  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED 
  SELECT dbo.Product.ProductId, dbo.Product.Name FROM dbo.Product WHERE dbo.Product.ProductId = 10", connection);

  SqlCacheDependency myProductDependency = new SqlCacheDependency(cmdProduct);

  if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
  {
    connection.Open();
  }

  using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdProduct.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
    }
  }

  HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("Product:10", product, myProductDependency, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, OnRemove);

}


//Callback
public static void OnRemove(string key, object cacheItem, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
//this fires directly and the reason is always DependencyChanged however nothing has changed in the database, weird!
}
```

I understand that there must be something wrogn with the query since http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx tells me "If these options or the isolation level is not set appropriately, the notification is fired immediately after the SELECT statement is executed." however I can't figure out what is wrong. The ProductId column is of type int and Name nvarchar(50)

Answer (score 1):

Watch [QN:Subscription Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365601.aspx) in SQL Profiler. Run your test case. There will be an event fired with `EventSubClass` value Subscription fired. the `TextData` will contain exactly the subscription notification [Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationsource(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0fkxc6y(v=vs.110).aspx) (I think it will be in the [`EventText`](http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotificationProfiler/QueryNotificationProfiler.xsd) XML element).

With this you will know exactly how is your query not conforming and you can fix the issue accordingly.

Comment: I am not really sure what I am supposed to look for:
http://s18.postimg.org/m8s0za3qx/Untitled_Copy.png

Comment: Click on the Subscriton Fired events. Look into the TextData panel (will be a large panel bellow the grid)

Comment: Ok, just a bunch of gibberish characters. Nothing about Info, source or type.